# How to judge if a NSManagedObject instance deleted from context?

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject

As we all know, a NSManagedObject would be deleted from its context after 'save to persistentStore' is made. I want to know what api could help me to judge whether it is deleted.

```
// MakeupModel is a subclass of NSManagedObject
MakeupModel *model = [MakeupModel MR_findFirstOrCreateByAttribute:@"materialId" withValue:@"221101010"];
model.materialId = model.materialId;
[MakeupModel MR_truncateAll];
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];



// Code will crash here because model has beed deleteed whose properties could not be visited.  But model is not a "nil" object, how can I judge whether it is deleted? Is there any apis could help?
if(model.materialId) {

}
```

Comment: You should `nil` the reference yourself after you delete it

Comment: If I do not make `nil` action, is there any api to help to make fault-tolerant?